# JSON Parser for GNUstep runtime (Objective-c 1.0?)

Tags: objective-c, json, gnustep

Is there a JSON Parser Library for GNUstep runtime (Objective-c 1.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is actually a version of the `NSJSONSerialization` class, which was included in Mac OS X 10.7.  See here:

http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSJSONSerialization.m

Comment: I am installing the latest release from here http://gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html but cannot find `NSJSONSerialization`: `NSJSONSerialization' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: Maybe it hasn't made it into the stable channel yet.  Just grab the latest version from the svn trunk.

Comment: I've wrote a comprehensive article in my blog http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2011/09/building-and-installing.html, Thanks @`sudo rm -rf`